# Mysql query minus issue

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

Hi Please consider the following table

```
user_id  city_id role_id 
 101      1       a
 101      2       b
 101      3       c
```

What I want is

```
Input                    Output
city id  role_id
1,2,3                   All user_ids present in city_id 1 and 2 and 3 
1,2       c             All user_ids present in city_id 1 and 2 and not present in role_id c 
1         b,c           All user_ids present in city_id 1 and not present in role_id b,c
2         a,c           All user_ids present in city_id 2 and not present  in role_id a,c
```

Whats the easiest way to do this? Note: I have a huge number of records in the table so performance also matters.

So in the above example 101 will be returned only if I pass city_id 1,2,3

I tried

```
select user_id,  city_id, role_id from foo_table where city_id in 
(1,2)  and role_id not in ('c') group by user_id having count(*) = 2;
```

and

```
select user_id,  city_id, role_id from foo_table where city_id in 
(1,2)  and user_id not in (select user_id from foo_table where role_id not in ('c'));
```

with incorrect results.

**Update:**
I need something like this

```
    select * from (select * from foo_table where city_id in (1)) s1
    inner join (select * from foo_table where city_id in (2)) s2 
    on s1.user_id = s2.user_id
    and s1.user_id not in (select distinct(user_id) from foo_table where role_id in('c'));
```

I am still testing it.

Comment: In the output table, city id for each record will be user's input?

Comment: yes output will be 3 records for above case

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework assignment...

Comment: nope live application scenario..may be a bad example..

Comment: why is every one down voting this? whats wrong? sry m a newbie on stack overflow.. :(

Comment: @Jdoe See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your question is too broad, thus the downvotes. You need to show what you tried, i.e. a stored procedure you tried which doesn't give you the result you want so we can see what you're trying to do. Include what you tried, sample output, (in table format instead of words) etc.

Comment: thanks @artm.. updated the post with queries i tried with no luck..

Comment: @Jdoe Also explain what "with no luck" means. Did you get an error? Did you get incorrect result? Did the query time out?

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling you may be after something more complex than what you see below, but I have tried to interpret your brief question literally. i.e. for different sets of criteria you request a list of user_id's meeting those criteria.[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfe3c/6)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_table
    (`user_id` int, `city_id` int, `role_id` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO foo_table
    (`user_id`, `city_id`, `role_id`)
VALUES
    (101, 1, 'a'),
    (101, 2, 'b'),
    (101, 3, 'c'),
    (101, 4, 'd')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
Input                    Output
city id  role_id
1,2,3                   All user_ids present in city_id 1 and 2 and 3 

select user_id 
from foo_table 
where city_id in (1,2,3) 
group by user_id
having count(distinct city_id) = 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfe3c/6/0)**:

```
| user_id |
|---------|
|     101 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
Input                    Output
1,2       c             All user_ids present in city_id 1 and 2 and not 

select user_id 
from foo_table 
where city_id in (1,2) 
and role_id not in ('c') 
group by user_id
having count(distinct city_id) = 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfe3c/6/1)**:

```
| user_id |
|---------|
|     101 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
Input       Output
1     b,c   All user_ids present in city_id 1 and not present in role_id b,c

select user_id 
from foo_table 
where city_id in (1) 
and role_id not in ('b','c') 
group by user_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfe3c/4/2)**:

```
| user_id |
|---------|
|     101 |
```

**Query 4**:

```
Input       Output
2     a,c   All user_ids present in city_id 2 and not present  in role_id a,c  

select user_id 
from foo_table 
where city_id in (2) 
and role_id not in ('a','c') 
group by user_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfe3c/4/3)**:

```
| user_id |
|---------|
|     101 |
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. the problem here is  query 1 will return source ids which are either in 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: if you could be less cryptic (brief) perhaps we could help more. you have (in your mind) something you want to achieve, but basically I have almost no idea what that is. query 1 will indeed return ids that are in 1 or 2 or 3 because that is what I believe you asked for. Take some time to explain exactly what you are seeking ( & edit the question, don't use comments for that).

Comment: I have changed query 1

Comment: moved all queries to use of `group by` & queries 1 & 2 use `having clause` in an effort to meet the updated requirements

Answer (score 0):

This is what i needed:

```
Select a.* 
From foo_table a , 
   (Select user_id 
    From foo_table 
    Where city_id in(1,2)   
          and role_id not in('c') 
    Group by user_id 
    Having count(*) = 2) b
Where a.city_id in(1,2)
       And a.city_id = b.city_id;
```